# MDX calculated Member not allowed multiple hierarchy tuple

Tags: excel, ssas, mdx, olap, cube

I've using a sql Table to generate filters on each dimensions for a value in a SSAS Cube.

[image: SQL Table]

The MDX Query is based on the column Query below, the calculated member is:

```
   AGGREGATE
    (
      IIF(Query= "" or ISEMPTY(Query),
           [Code].[_KeyQuery].[ALL],
           StrToTuple('('+ Query+')')
           ),[Measures].[Value]
    )
```

I have to work with pivot Table in Excel. It works perfectly, the value is correctly filter on each dimension member. If i use a query like this, it's ok.

```
[Level].[LevelCode].&[A],[Status].[StatusCode].&[ST]
```

But now i need adding the possibility to filter on multiple dimensions members. For exemple, using a query :

```
[Level].[LevelCode].&[A],[Level].[LevelCode].&[X],[Status].[StatusCode].&[ST]
```

It doesn't works, i've try changing the query  like this:

```
{[Level].[LevelCode].&[A],[Level].[LevelCode].&[X]},[Status].[StatusCode].&[ST]
```

but the StrToTuple() function causes error. I don't know how to filter in multiple values for a same dimension hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it will always be a tuple then no need to use AGGREGATE just a tuple should return the value:

```
  IIF(
    Query= "" OR ISEMPTY(Query),
    (
      [Code].[_KeyQuery].[ALL]
     ,[Measures].[Value]
    )
   ,StrToTuple('('+ Query +',[Measures].[Value])')
  )
```

Or this version:

```
   StrToTuple(
      '('
      + IIF(
          Query= "" OR ISEMPTY(Query)
         ,[Code].[_KeyQuery].[ALL]
         ,Query 
       )
     +',[Measures].[Value])'
    )
```

---

possible approach for decision between tuple and set

Add a column to your control table "TupleOrSet" with values of either "T" or "S". Then you could amend your code to something like this:

```
  IIF(
    Query= "" OR ISEMPTY(Query),
    (
      [Code].[_KeyQuery].[ALL]
     ,[Measures].[Value]
    )
   ,IIF(
       TupleOrSet = "T"
      ,StrToTuple('('+ Query +',[Measures].[Value])')
      ,AGGREGATE( StrToSet('{'+ Query +'}'), [Measures].[Value])
    )
  )
```

---

note

A tuple is a definite point in the cube space so cannot therefore be made up of two members from the same hierarchy - this would create coordinates that are non-determinant

Comment: Ok same result but I still have the same problem using multiple values ​​for the same dimension. If the query is like '[dim].[code].&[value],[dim2].[code].&[Value]' it works perfectly but not if i use a query like : '[dim].[code].&[value1],[dim].[code].&[Value2]'

Comment: this was not specified in your question

Comment: this  '[dim].[code].&[value1],[dim].[code].&[Value2]' would need to be aggreagted into a single point before being used in a tuple

Comment: Ok thx, I understand better. But not solution with dynamic query ? I can use two columns query1, query2 => tuple1 + tuple2. But i need to use more than two members in the same hierarchy

Comment: Dynamic for multiple members is `StrToSet()` instead of `StrToTuple()` . Because this part is a set: `{[Level].[LevelCode].&[A],[Level].[LevelCode].&[X]}`

Comment: Fine ! I use StrToSet() with cross join {[Level].[LevelCode].&[A],[Level].[LevelCode].&[X]}*{[OtherDimension].[Code].&[member]}. It's works thanks !